# DisplayPort adapter instead of VGA?

Tags: display, vga, displayport

I just bought an LG 24M38H monitor in order to connect it to my Dell Latitude e6510 laptop. I connected them through a VGA cable and the result was quite disappointed. The colors of the external monitor are washed up, and the text is very blurry. In fact, it is far more comfortable to read a text from the 15'' laptop screen than the 24'' brand new monitor.

I suspect that the problem occurs due to the poor quality of the VGA signal. Since the monitor provides a VGA and an HDMI input, and my laptop provides a VGA and a DisplayPort output, should the quality be improved if I hook up a DisplayPort to HDMI adapter to the laptop and connect it to the HDMI input of the monitor?

In that case, should I buy an expensive adapter, or a relatively cheap one should be just the same?

**P.S.**
I use Linux Mint 17.3 with nvidia 340 drivers *(the recommented)*, the resolution for both devices is 1920x1080, and I fiddled a lot with the on board monitor's settings before I ask this question.

**P.S.2**
I just checked that the DP++ logo is on the port. Does that mean that it is active? If so, does it make any difference?

Any thought would be appreciated.

Comment: This particular monitor has unusually poor image quality with an analog input. Normally, at this resolution, the difference should be hard to notice.

Comment: @David Schwartz So, with a DisplayPort adapter, are there chances for improvement?

Comment: Yes. That's what I would do.

Comment: What about testing with another VGA cable? I agreed with @DavidSchwartz... I work everyday on a 24" screen plugged with VGA with no noticeable quality lost.

Answer (score -1):

Re: P.S.2.   I spoke with Startech and they recommend a non-active (ie passive) cable when you are using DP++ port. This is because the HDMI signal is generated in the computer and you are not wanting to recreate another HDMI signal from a HDMI signal. The Active cable was for a DP signal that you wanted to change to a HDMI signal if the computer only had DP output.  I have not tested this yet because I am waiting for my MDP to DP splitter.  I do not know if you can set the DP++ port to output standard DP signals and them use an active cable to convert it to HDMI.  That will be my first test. Linux Mint 18, i3, NUC set up for media useage.

Comment: I quite agree with you, yet I used an active cable to a D++ port, and it works. However, I haven't tested weather it would be better or just the same with a passive cable.